# No route to port 80 while HTTPS works

Tags: networking, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, ufw

I can't figure out how to troubleshoot this. Whenever I try opening a website using HTTP, I get something like:

```
$ wget example.com
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|<IP_HERE>|:80... failed: No route to host.
```

Meanwhile, HTTPS works fine:

```
$ wget https://example.com
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|<IP_HERE>|:443... connected.
```

Of course, my first places to look were my firewall and nginx configs. However, `ufw` shows port 80 as an already open port:

```
$ ufw allow http
Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)
```

...and the logic behind redirecting to HTTPS in my nginx config seems rather good to me:

```
listen 80; # managed by Certbot

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
```

I have also tried `nmap`-ing the (Ubuntu 16.04) server both from the machine itself (`nmap localhost`) and from  the external location (`nmap <ip-here>`). Surprisingly, HTTP seems to be closed from the external location. Disabling firewall also didn't help. `netstat -lnp | grep "80"` shows me that nginx is indeed listening on port 80:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8845/nginx -g daemo
```

There's nothing written in the nginx logs.

I'm not sure where else to look. I can't pinpoint this issue.

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: In addition to @MichaelHampton’s comment, I’d try to open the address in chrome browser and then inspecting the page then choosing Network, that will show you what happens in the background. Also, just to understand if it’s a firewall issue, I would stop the firewall service, retry wget and restart the firewall but that would tell me if it’s a firewall issue or not.

Comment: Did you enable a [firewall in Hetzner-Robot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zekXr.png)?

Comment: Disabling firewall and trying `wget` again did nothing. Also something weird is that even `wget localhost` from the server gives me `...(localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: No route to host.`, which most definitely doesn't sound like a firewall problem. Firewall in Hetzner-Robot was enabled (by default I think, I don't remember turning it on), but disabling it also did nothing.

Comment: what does `ip a s` and `ip r s` show you? and whats in `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf` (you may mask your public ip by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx or similar)

Comment: just to make sure we won't work on a problem already solved: I can wget your blog via http and https without errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon a server re-start, I've discovered that there was something wrong with nginx (I couldn't start it).

I then looked at `journalctl -xe` and discovered that nginx was missing one of the dependencies for a separate nginx config (`php7.0-mbstring`), which was preventing it from starting. The weird thing here is that doing `nginx -t` and restarting nginx via systemd didn't discover that error before the restart.

After the restart, I've made sure to install that missing PHP dependency. That made nginx start properly and the HTTP traffic forwarded to HTTPS from that point on.

My assumption to the core of this problem is that some PHP process had to be restarted (perhaps `php7.0-fpm`, I'm really not familiar with the PHP ecosystem) for the nginx to notice the dependency change, and that a combo of those two problems caused some really unexpected consequences.